# Algolia Rails records with specific parent id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algolia

I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction with the `algolia-rails` gem (and Algolia in general):

Currently I have these two models:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  include AlgoliaSearch

  belongs_to :account

  algoliasearch do
    attribute :account_id, :full_name, :email, :tax_id, :contact_name

    searchableAttributes ['full_name', 'email', 'tax_id', 'contact_name']

    customRanking ['asc(full_name)']
  end
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contacts
end
```

I would like to retrieve only matching records for a given `account_id` on the contacts indexes so the resulting query won't look for contact IDs that don't belong to an specific account. So `current_account.contacts.algolia_search("Tom")` should not fetch IDs from other accounts contacts.

Looks like it has something to do with facets but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, It had a lot to do with facets. I modified the `Contact` model to add this inside the `algoliasearch` block:

`attributesForFaceting ['account_id']`

Then to filter contacts matching "Tom" by an specific `account_id` (let's suppose 3) it's as easy as:

`Contact.algolia_search("Tom", {facets: 'account_id', facetFilters: "account_id:3"})`